# Is usage of views in Azure Data Explorer could harm the efficiency of the queries?

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer

Per my understanding, ADX can opimize the query by choosing the order of where clauses.
What happens when one uses view in the query, and both the view and the query have where clauses?
Is a view like a black box aka where clauses of the view are stand alone and optimization would run within the view and within the query seperatly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ADX and many database systems for that matter, when you use a view in a query, and both have WHERE clauses, the query optimizer does not treat the view as a black box. Instead, it expands the view into the main query and optimizes the entire query as a whole, considering all WHERE clauses together. This approach leads to more efficient query execution than if the view and the query were optimized separately.

In terms of query optimization, ADX optimizes the final, expanded query. This includes optimizing across the boundaries of the original view and the outer query. The optimizer looks at the WHERE clauses in both the view and the query against the view, and decides the most efficient way to execute the combined query.

The presence of WHERE clauses both in the view and in the outer query can lead to more complex optimization decisions. The optimizer might push down some predicates, combine others, or re-order them based on various factors like data distribution, index availability, and statistical information about the data.